# PHP / MySQL remove diuplicate names from a list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

We have a MySql table view for the user registered from different districts, with the following columns:

```
District, City, User_Name
```

We are displaying the data in tabular form from the db with group by clause.

The mysql query is:

```
SELECT district, city, count(*) as reg_total FROM tabelname group by district, city;
```

Then we store the resulting values in two arrays, `$district` and `$Cities` and is being displayed with PHP:

```php
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $reg_total = array_sum($data_total);
        $count = 0;
        echo "<tr><td><b>District</b></td><td><b>City</b></td><td><b>Total</b></td></tr>";
        foreach ($Cities as $city)
        {
            echo "<tr><td >$district[$count]</td><td >$city</td><td >$data_total[$count]</td></tr>";
            $count++;
        }

    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For example:

```
District, City, User_Name
A1  B1 U1
A1  B1 U2
A1  B2 U3
A2  B3 U4
A2  B4 U5
A3  B4 U6
A3  B4 U6
```

What we want to display is, in the first column, we do not want to repeat the District names, for example it should display like this:

```
District, City, User_Name
A1  B1 U1
    B1 U2
    B2 U3
A2  B3 U4
    B4 U5
A3  B4 U6
    B4 U6
```

Any solution with plain PHP will be appreciated.

Comment: and what is your try?

Comment: we can use distinct in our query to db, but it will eliminate many rows.

Comment: Please add your PHP code, currently this question is too broad and should be closed.

Comment: `group by district` should'nt resolve it ?

Comment: It's not a mysql related problem, but a PHP displaying problem. He wants to print duplicates rows, but omitting repeating district in its html table.

Comment: @Florian Lemaitre you are absolutely right.

Comment: You should add some php code to your question with your query and html table. Currently there's too many possibilities to answer your question.

Comment: @Florian Lemaitre It was not added before just to keep the things simple and easy to understand I just added the mysql query and php code being used. Btw , once working, we will use this code in Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check what is Distict name during each row fetch:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM districts ORDER BY District";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    print '<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>District</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>User_Name</td>
        </tr>';
    $tmp = $name = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($tmp != $row['District']){
            $name = $row['District'];
            $tmp = $row['District'];
        }else{
            $name = '';
        }
        print '<tr>
             <td>' . $name . '</td>
             <td>' . $row['City'] . '</td>
             <td>' . $row['User_Name'] . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    print '</table>';
?>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php
    $district = '';
    foreach($resultset as $row)
    {
        if($district != $row->district)
        {
            echo $row->district.' ';
        }
        echo $row->city.' '.$row->username;
        echo '<br/>';
        $district = $row->district;
    }
?>
```